# Unable to close the modal box using span's class with GetElementByClass

Tags: javascript, html

I have multiple modal boxes with different class and id's, however, I couldn't able to close the second one with the `<span class="classname">&times;</span>` using `GetElementByClass array`

```js
var layoutmodal = document.getElementById("layoutmodal");
var layoutbtn = document.getElementById("layoutbtn");
var layoutspan = document.getElementsByClassName("layoutclose")[0];
layoutbtn.onclick = function() {
  layoutmodal.style.display = "block";
}
layoutspan.onclick = function() {
  layoutmodal.style.display = "none";
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == layoutmodal) {
    layoutmodal.style.display = "none";
  }
}

var colorsmodal = document.getElementById("colorsmodal");
var colorsbtn = document.getElementById("colorsbtn");
var colorsspan = document.getElementsByClassName("colorsclose")[0];
colorsbtn.onclick = function() {
  colorsmodal.style.display = "block";
}
colorsspan.onclick = function() {
  colorsmodal.style.display = "none";
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == colorsmodal) {
    colorsmodal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="layoutmodal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content" style="border-radius:7px;">
    <span class="layoutclose">&times;</span>
    <p style="font-family: verdana;text-align:center;">Choose Layout</p>
    <div>
      <img src="images/layouts/lay1.png" class="imglayout" alt="" style="margin-left: 15%;" />
      <img src="images/layouts/lay2.png" class="imglayout" alt="" style="margin-left: 10%;" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="colorsmodal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="colorsclose">&times;</span>
    <p style="font-family: verdana;text-align:center;">Choose Color</p>
    <div>
      <img src="images/layouts/lay1.png" alt="" style="margin-left: 18%;" />
      <img src="images/layouts/lay2.png" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Able to close the first modal however, the second can't be closed.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The code appears to work, though your question left out the two buttons to open the modal dialogs. If those are added, both of the "close" buttons do work.

Comment: Note that if you have more than one of the "Colors" modal dialogs on the page, the code won't work because it only acts on the first "close" button on the page.

Comment: @Pointy I have button added, and i have only one close for each popup with different class names. Yet, I m still not able to close the second modal box

Comment: By "second modal box" do you mean the "colors" box in the code you posted?

Comment: yes, I meant the colors box

Comment: Well it works fine in the version of the code you posted.

Comment: `layoutbtn`/ `colorsbtn` is not in the html

Comment: you are right pointy I just checked the same piece of code in another system and it works fine, needs to go through the whole 11000 lines of HTML again, Thanks for the time though.

Answer (score 0):

You are explicitly accessing the first element and completely ignore the other results using the following statement:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("colorsclose")[0]
```

But you probably mean to do something like:

```js
for (let element of document.getElementsByClassName("colorsclose")) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: The code actually works however, it's not clear what the problem is. Your comment is accurate but it doesn't matter if there's only one of those elements on the page.

Comment: Right, but again it's not clear whether there is more than one of those things on the page. The question is unclear: does "second" mean the second modal in the posted code, or the second *instance* of one (or both) of those? I don't know the answer.

Comment: Yes, I now see your point. I guess I misinterpreted the question

Answer (score 0):

How about simplier & generic code?

this code fit any count of modal as long you have `modal` and `modal-close` classes on your modal.
With this no need to hardcode all modals.

```js
var ms = document.querySelectorAll('.modal'); // which is closen
ms.forEach((m) => {
    var mc = m.querySelector('.modal-close'); // which is listen close event
    mc.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        m.style.display = "none";
    })
})
```

```html
<div id="layoutmodal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content" style="border-radius:7px;">
    <span class="modal-close">&times;</span>
    <p style="font-family: verdana;text-align:center;">Choose Layout</p>
    <div>
        <img src="images/layouts/lay1.png" class="imglayout" alt="" style="margin-left: 15%;" />
        <img src="images/layouts/lay2.png" class="imglayout" alt="" style="margin-left: 10%;" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="colorsmodal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="modal-close">&times;</span>
    <p style="font-family: verdana;text-align:center;">Choose Color</p>
    <div>
        <img src="images/layouts/lay1.png" alt="" style="margin-left: 18%;" />
        <img src="images/layouts/lay2.png" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Don't forget to mark as solved BTW. ;)